# Remove word 'Test' in laravel 8 logout dropdown

Tags: logout, laravel-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmUQm.png)

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <i class="now-ui-icons loader_gear"></i>
                  <p>
                    <span class="d-lg-none d-md-block">Tetapan</span>
                  </p>
                  {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                    </a>

                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                        @csrf
                    </form>
                </div>
            </li>
```

How to remove 'Test' word appears on logout dropdown in Laravel 8?

Comment: Is the `{{ Auth::user()->name }}` by any means `test` itself?

Comment: Yes you right @DimitriMostrey ,  I happen to think that {{ Auth::user()->name }} is for something else, thank you. I'm still newbie in laravel

Comment: If you have any doubt what a the value of a collection is, just dump and die it's content `{{ dd(Auth::user) }}` or `{{ dd(Auth::user()->name) }}`
Happy learning!

Comment: Alright. Thanks for your explanation.  It helps me a lot.